# Iterate through column, find match and send email based on cell value

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a spreadsheet (here -> https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1U0A8PmKYxkXn8SrfKOo6XsJb-XxkJNYZqd0QIKkFsP4/edit?usp=sharing) that collects data from forms and perform several if functions to categorize answers.
What I need to do is to send follow up emails (reminders) based on cell value (sheet "Code extension data + Minimum desc. fill", last column "Reminder Minimum descriptions"). In order to do that, I suppose I must loop through the column, find a match ("Keep sending reminder", "Stop sending reminder") and send mail.
But what ends up happening is that the code shoots 73 follow up messages. I don't know 73, if I have only 2 rows with "Keep sending email".

```
function sendEmail() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1lzc7-WRxEBQc5D_SR0F-d- 
9PhQjmVk37UOgBQTGw3_Q");
var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Code extension data + Minimum desc. fill');
var lastRow = sh.getLastRow();
var data = sh.getRange(1,28,lastRow,28).getValues();
for (i=0; i < data.length;i++){
var num = parseInt(data[i]);
if (num = "Keep sending reminder") {
var emailAddress = "email@email.com";
var message = "test body";
var subject = "test subject";
MailApp.sendEmail({
name: "Your Name",
to: emailAddress,
subject: subject,
htmlBody: message
}); 
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `if` statement is comparing a `number` to a `string` ("Keep sending reminder") which will never evaluate as true.   There is no need to use `parseInt` for what you are trying to do.  Also, you are looping over `string[][]`, so you have to use `data[i][columnIndex]` to access the column you expect to find "keep sending reminder" in.

```js
function sendEmail() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1lzc7-WRxEBQc5D_SR0F-d-9PhQjmVk37UOgBQTGw3_Q");
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Code extension data + Minimum desc. fill');
  var lastRow = sh.getLastRow();
  var data = sh.getRange(1,28,lastRow,28).getValues();
  for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
    //var num = parseInt(data[i]);
    if (data[i][27] === "Keep sending reminder") {
      var emailAddress = "email@email.com";
      var message = "test body";
      var subject = "test subject";
      MailApp.sendEmail({
        name: "Your Name",
        to: emailAddress,
        subject: subject,
        htmlBody: message
      }); 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @MarcoFernandes - you're welcome.  You can mark the answer as accepted if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your if statement only has a single equal sign, use == or === even better.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, Mark, but when I change it to "==" or "===", the email message is not sent. Any other suggestion?